# what is the reason for this error with here() in knitr?

Tags: r

I'm running the following code in R Markdown.

```
products <- read_csv(here("data", "5000_products.csv"))
```

But I'm getting the following error. 
Error in here("data", "5000_products.csv"): unused arguments ("data", "5000_products.csv")

I have installed and loaded the `library(here)`

Not sure what could be the problem here, could someone please help?

Comment: I'm not getting the unused arguments error. When you run `here("data", "5000_products.csv")` only do you still get the error?

Comment: yes, it is very strange. If just run the particular code chunk, I do not get the error, if i knit the entire .rmd file I get the error

Comment: Could you make a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610#5963610) where the error occurs (including necessary packages)?

Comment: is the `require(here)' actually included in the Rmd file? Or did you just run and loaded it in your console?

Comment: @Tomas it is in the .Rmd file as a code knitr code chunk